# What additional CSS do I have to add to make HTML tables show cell borders?

Tags: html, css

Here is what I have in CSS:

```
table.defaultTable
{
    border-style: Solid;
    border-width: thin;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px;
}
```

This is what it the table looks like:

[image]

As you can see, the cells inside the table do not have a solid border around them.

Comment: Slightly off topic - You can use shorthand for border, `border:1px solid #000`.

Comment: If you want border around cells (not around table itself) you have to apply border to `td`, not `table`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
table.defaultTable td
{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

This will put a border around each cell in your `defaultTable`. However, there will be space between them. To remove that space, you also need  the following:

```
table.defaultTable { border-collapse: collapse; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YH46T/1/

Comment: Thanks for the border-collapse suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use rule

```
table td{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Of course you can use [class or id selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Writing_efficient_CSS) on table for separation of rule influence. But main idea is set border to the table's cells, not the header, because for header you should use [th](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/th) elements.

Comment: just beat me to it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a border simply add the line `border: 1px solid #000;` to your css.

```
td{
border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would acheive this by using adjacent selectors, like so:

```
table {
border: 1px solid #000;
}
tr {
border-top: 1px solid #000;
}
tr + tr {
border-top: 1px solid red;
}
td {
border-left: 1px solid #000;
}
td + td {
border-left: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try it with

```
border-collapse: separate;
```

See here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-collapse.asp

Another way could be to define a class "cell-border" (or similar) and give that class a border property.

Comment: `border-collapse: separate` is the default value, and won't change anything unless the table is inheriting `collapse` from something else.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the [`border` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border) on *cells*. Setting it on the `table` element sets only a border on the table as a whole. A minimal rule would be

```
th, td { border: solid }
```

In general, a table can have two kinds of cells, headers cells `th` and data cells `td`. In a table that presents tabular data, rather than acts as a layout tool only, there is usually a row of header cells that specify column headers.